# Copy an excel file with Macros and New Tabs in the ribbon to another computer

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm working with Microsoft Excel 2013. I'm using couple of macros I did and I made a new tab in the ribbon menu which shows the macros I did so that I can click on the this created tab then click on one of the macros to run. It's working beautifully on my machine. Now I want to move this excel file to another machine to work same as in my machine. First when I copied the file it didn't work and I realized that I need to save it with macros `.xlsm`. But I still can't find the new tab created in my original excel file neither I can find the macros listed in the commands. I need this as I'm going to share this with colleagues and I want them to be able to use it once they download the excel file. Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Excel Options dialog as shown below
[image]

Click on Import / Export to import or export your ribbon customization.

Pass it on to your colleagues and let them import your ribbon customization using the same method described above.

For the macros, they need to be in your colleagues system as well to work when clicked on them.